# Regex to read prop file entry does not capture group properly

Tags: java, regex

I have to parse a property file having key value pair and some of the lines may be commented (! or # , both are valid).

Exa:

```
key1 val1
Key2 val2
#key3 val3
 # key4 val4
# It does not have = symbol
# Spaces can be any where.
...
```

If line is not commented then read key and value as matcher's group values. I used following RegEx and code snippet but its not capturing keys and values as expected:

```
    String inputs[] = {
            "key1 val1",
            "Key2 val2",
            "#key3 val3",
            " # key4 val4"              
    };

    Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(\\s*[^#!]\\s*)(\\w*)\\s+(\\w*).*$");
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

        System.out.println("Input: " + inputs[i]);
        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(inputs[i]);
        if(matcher.matches()) {
            int groupCount = matcher.groupCount();
            if(groupCount > 0) {
                for (int j = 1; j <= groupCount; j++) {
                    System.out.println(j + " " +  matcher.group(j));
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(matcher.group());
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("No match found.");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
Input: key1 val1
1 k
2 ey1
3 val1

Input: Key2 val2
1 K
2 ey2
3 val2

Input: #key3 val3
No match found.

Input:  # key4 val4
No match found.
```

My thinking was:

```
^           - Start of line
(\\s*[^#!]\\s*) - space(s) followed by NO # or ! followed by space(s) 
(\\w*)      - Key
\\s+        - spaces(s)
(\\w*)      - Value
.*          - Anything
$           - End of line
```

Please help me to understand what is wrong here. 
Why it's capturing first character of key as a group?

Comment: Why don you use Java Properties files?

Comment: +1 to @JavierDiaz: Java property files have the syntax you describe and you don't need to parse it, just read it as a property file and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check for no # or !. You can simply do: `/^(?<key>\w+)\s*(?<value>.*)/gm`

Javafied regex: `^(?<key>\\w+)\\s*(?<value>.*)` (use the multiline option)

Demo+explanation: http://regex101.com/r/aM0xK1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not gonna give you the solution, but I will give you the answers to your questions:

`(\\s*[^#!]\\s*)` <- this is why is capturing the first chracter. And you have 2 options:

1. Use a non capturing group `(?:Hi, im a non capturing group)` (See the `(?: )`)

   Ps: Using a non capturing group will increase the internal pointer of the regex, so it's not really what you want. So better use the second option.
2. Use the lookbehind and watch if the character before X is a `#!`

As a third solution use Java Properties files [With this pretty example.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Input: key1 val1
1 k
2 ey1
3 val1
```

this is correct based on your regex.

```
(\\s*[^#!]\\s*) this is the group1.
```

it means, matching a single character, not #, not !. there could be spaces before and after the character. so for the first line in your prop file. "k" is the character.

you may want to check negative look behind. it is Zero-Width Assertions.

for example like this: (group 2 would be the key)

```
^\s*(?!<#|!)\s*(\w*).....
```

hope it helps...